# OpenCV too slow after building it for MingW

Tags: c++, opencv, build, cmake, mingw

I have OpenCV 2.4.9 and I wanted to use it in Codeblocks with MingW. I followed this guide: [guide](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:q9A23TkwhlEJ:kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a) to build the .dll.a and .dll files with CMake and everything runs smoothly. In the past I had used the **vc10** .dll and .dll.a files to run my programs with the OpenCV C API and it was running pretty fast. But now that I used the new libraries (I had some errors with the vc10 version) it runs around 5 times slower. What is causing this? I didn't find an option for Release or Debug library version. Maybe I built the libraries for Debugging?

Comment: in cmake there should be `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` option, use `RELEASE` there. And/or uncheck `BUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO`

Comment: @Micka I tried that and I noticed that the new dll files are a little smaller in size, but still no speed improvements.

Comment: I noticed a similar problem. on Windows with mingw, it is pretty slow while on linux with the same version of gcc the running time is about half. After using very sleepy profiler, I noticed that a windows process : RtInitializerExepctionChain was running in // with my code and was taking between 45% and 60% of the time. I was unable to find the reason. If by any chance you have the same problem and find a solution, I'll be glad if you could post it.